# How to find the value of $c$ using the mean value theorem?

Tags: calculus

So I'm doing Mean Value theorem homework which states 
$$f'(c)=\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$$

I have $f(x)=e^{\frac{-x}{2}}$ over the interal [0,12]. Using the mean value theorem I have$$f'(c)=\frac{e^{-6}-e^0}{12}=-.0831267707$$  So for $f'(x)= f'(x)=\frac{-e^{\frac{-x}{2}}}{2}$. So I need to find the exact value for which $f'(x)=\frac{-e^{\frac{-x}{2}}}{2}-.0831267707$ Which I am having problems with. Thanks for all the help! Here's a pic of the actual question.

Comment: Your derivative is incorrect.

Comment: Also:  you cannot find $c$ using the MVT, it's not a theorem that gives a computation for values, it only says at least one exists. There could be many, MANY points.

Comment: T.Bongers I just realized this, thanks for pointing that out. @So would you have any insight on how to find $c$? I'm just going by the question and I have no idea on how to go about solving for it.

Comment: If you write the correct derivative, it should be evident how to solve for $c$ with logarithms.

Comment: Would $\frac{-e^{\frac{x}{2}}}{2}$ be the correct derivative?

Comment: @AndréNicolas Isn't it supposed to be $-\frac{1}{2e^{x/2}}$, due to negative exponent.

Comment: Yes, I missed the fact OP had not written $\frac{-e^{-x/2}}{2}$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas sorry for the mistake. Just missed the negative on the exponent. However, I'm still having trouble finding the value of $c$. Would you mind expelling the process you mentioned in one of your previous comments? Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: Let your $-0.083\dots$ number (which I have not checked) be $-k$. We want $\frac{-e^{-c/2}}{2}=-k$. So we want $e^{-c/2}=2k$. Take ln of both sides. We get $-c/2=\ln(2k)$ so $c=-2\ln(2k)$. You know $k$. Now use the calculator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like said, your derivative is wrong,

$$\frac{d}{dx}f(x) = -\frac{1}{2e^{x/2}}$$

Going back to the MVT,

$$f'(c)=\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$$
$$-\frac{1}{2e^{c/2}} = \frac{e^{-6} - 1}{12}$$
$$-\frac{6}{e^{c/2}} = {e^{-6} - 1}$$
$$-6 = e^{c/2}*(e^{-6}-1)$$
$$e^{c/2} = -\frac{6}{e^6-1}$$
$$\ln(e^{c/2}) = \ln(\frac{-6}{e^{-6}-1})$$
$$c/2 = \ln(\frac{-6}{e^{-6}-1})$$
$$c = 2\ln(\frac{-6}{e^{-6}-1})$$

Comment: Thanks a lot! Appreciate it.